# Nested blocks in Pelican and Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, pelican

Hi I'm trying to make a nested block in my pelican theme that wraps a for loop:

```
{% block content %}
{% block test_block %}
{% for subcategory in article.subcategories %}
Stuff here
{% endfor %}
{% endblock test_block %}
{% endblock content %}
```

But my theme is not compiling. If I take the for loop out of the 'test_block' everything runs as expected. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: The jinja docs say that this is possible. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#named-block-end-tags  Have you tried different names for the inner block?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I have tried different names for the inner block and nothing.

Comment: Are you loading the subcategory plugin? You need that in order to use subcategories. https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/subcategory